# heroku rake db:migrate not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dbmigrate

I am getting this error when running heroku rake db:migrate:

```
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg   is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

I looked online and found to add the 'pg' gem.  I added it using gem install pg and also put it in my gem file.  I have done a bundle install.  When I try and do the command 'sudo gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter', it tells me the gem can not be found.

Also, I added 'pg' to my gemfile and tried to run my code on my local machine and it would not run because it could not find pg.  I somehow got pg to install and my program works again on my local computer but it still gives me the error when performing heroku rake db:migrate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've added `gem 'pg'` to your gemfile, you'll need to also run `bundle` from the terminal under your application root folder as this will regenerate your 'Gemfile.lock' file.

Then commit your changes, and do a `git push heroku` that should do the trick.